# UIScrollView somehow able to get stuck below minimumZoomScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

I've set a `minimumZoomScale` to `1.0` on my `UIScrollView`.

Naturally, you are able to pinch inwards to zoom out (making the content smaller) to a scale below 1.0 and the `scrollView` will automatically zoom back out to your `minimumZoomScale` upon pinch gesture release.

However, every once in a while, the scrollView won't do this behavior, and will just get stuck. It will just sit at about a `zoomScale` of `0.6`. Re-initiating the pinch gesture seems to snap it back out.

I can get this to happen a few times out of a dozen tries just by pinching.

Here is a delegate implementation that may or may not be affecting zoom:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
if([scrollView isEqual:self.resultScrollView])
    return self.resultScrollView.resultImageView; }
```

Any ideas on why this occurs? I don't believe I am affecting the scrollView with any special code. Thanks

Comment: Do you perform any extra logic while zooming or you let the UIScrollView do it's magic by itself?

Comment: Just added a delegate implementation that I use.

Comment: Maybe implement `scrollViewWillBeginZooming:withView:`, `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` and `scrollViewDidZoom:` delegate methods to debug what is happening, like checking the state of the gesture (which seems the cuplrit) and maybe reset the gesture whenever you end the previous gesture as a small hack/fix =)